# ngFor netsted array with objects in mat select option

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-form-field, mat-select

I have mat form field with option select

```html
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>TestMat</mat-label>
          <mat-select placeholder="TestMat"  [formControl]="testControl">  
                <mat-option *ngFor="let arr of arrTmp" [value]="arr">
               {{arr.name}}
            </mat-option>           
            </mat-select>   
        </mat-form-field>
```

where arrTmp =

```
[
    [{
        "name": "name1",
        "id": "1"
    }],

    [{
        "name": "name2",
        "id": "2"
    }, {
        "name": "name3",
        "id": "2"
    }]

]
```

as a result inside of mat form field i have

```
[object Object]
[object Object],[object Object]
```

how i can display arr.name normally?

Comment: Well, simplest would be, to flatMap or reduce your array:
see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use one extra for loop for nested array,
please see the below code

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>TestMat</mat-label>
          <mat-select placeholder="TestMat"  [formControl]="testControl">
               <ng-container *ngFor="let arr of arrTmp">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of arr" [value]="item">
                {{item.name}}
              </mat-option>  
               </ng-container> 
            </mat-select>   
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: i forgot about ng container, also it works

Answer (score 1):

You can add an element like a span, add it a ngFor looping on the first array, and then use your current ngFor to foop on the nested array.

So this would mean doing something like :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>TestMat</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="TestMat"  [formControl]="testControl"> 
      <span *ngFor="let mainArr of arrTmp">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let arr of mainArr" [value]="arr">
       {{arr.name}}
        </mat-option>           
      </span>
    </mat-select>   
</mat-form-field>
```